# Apache beam python fileio.MatchFiles performance

Tags: python, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm using `fileio.MatchFiles` to load a large amount of image files from Google Cloud Storage.
The files are under one GCS bucket and their names satisfy some patterns. I noticed that the subsequent transformations will not run before all the files are listed. When there are more than 100k files, the listing becomes very very slow.

I wonder if this is the expected behavior. Also, I'm looking for optimizations that could help the performance. I'm thinking about doing something like

```
files = [
  p | f"match {u}" >> fileio.MatchFiles(f"gs://bucket/{u}*.jpg")
  for u in "a..z"
]
files  
  | beam.Flatten() ...
```

Comment: That's the behaviour we should expect for batch pipelines

Comment: Got it. I'm just looking for a parallel version of `fileio.MatchFiles` which shard the files and runs faster.

Comment: I observed the same behaviour. Did you manage to optimise it? Another option is to generate a text file with all the images and use it as the main source.

Comment: I optimized it by using a different data source which allows parallelism.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to optimise MatchFiles at all? I'm aiming to read 10+ million files from a GCS bucket and the match file step takes upto 40+ minutes to read files.

Comment: You said you used a different data source which allows parallelism.  Can you expand on that?  What did you end up doing?

Comment: @Kolban I ended up using the same list of objects stored in Cloud Datastore with additional filtering steps.